# How to check which src causes https to be invalid?

Tags: facebook, https

The last couple of days i came across a bunch of https issues (just altering facebook apps to work with https). Now when all files are on the same website everything is easy to alter also using `//www.domain.com/etc` and ofcourse FB._https = {window.location.protocol== "https"};

is a time saver.

But now i have a file which uses get_file_content('http://www.somesite') and i can find the src that causes the https to be insecure.

Is there some firebug / webdeveloper tab i should look at???? How to find the troubling src??

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you look at the net tab of firebug and set it just to show image responses?

Comment: turns out google chrome console was a big help http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/faq/